# Cordova 3.4 iOS app crashes on iOS 8.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I have used Crodova 3.4 version for iOS app. When i try to launch it on iOS 8.1.1 it crashes.

xCode version : 5.1 and 6.0.1 used for it.

I have created ipa and install it using diawi link, from http://diawi.com.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of me had the same problem and asked me for help...

After a short bugfixing in `Xcode` I saw that the modules installed of `cordova` are crashing...

He had to update the plugins, like `Facebook` login, and `QR Code` Reader, to fix it.

After the update, everything was ok